# Stuck in EDL mode after flashing

Tags: rooting, root-access, redmi, unbricking

Solved:

> I bricked my Redmi Note 4 (mido, Snapdragon) 4 years ago and couldn't
> fix it back then. As far as I remember it showed no sign of life (not
> even red led) But yesterday I thought of giving it a go and found that
> it was being detected by the PC.
>
> Condition:
>
> - When I connect it to PC (with battery) red led blinks once per second
> - When i disconnect the battery pin it stops blinking and gets detected in the MiFlash Tool (which wasn't the case with battery
>   plugged)
> - It gets detected on PC as QUSB_HUB in both the above cases
> - When I tried Flashing the latest as well as an old fastboot stock rom (Global) with the MiFlash tool I am getting this error:
>
> ````
> /c:"^product: *MSM8953"   || fastboot -s 28ca11bb getvar product  
> 2>&1  | findstr /r /c:"^product: *mido"   || echo Missmatching image
> and device ```
>
> PS. It doesn't has a recovery i think. I bricked it while Unlocking
> the bootloader (I don't remember exactly but that's the condition I
> think)
> ````

**UPDATE**: I can flash now but it doesn't seem to boot up. Every time I plug it to PC it just keeps showing EDL mode. I tried vol up + power 20 sec. and pressing the power button for 30 to 60 sec. but it doesn't come out of EDL.

Any reply would be highly appreciated.

Comment: flash in EDL mode

Comment: Hi alecxs I've heard a lot of you on other threads! I tried putting it in EDL mode by shorting the pins but when I checked devices it's showing Diagnostics 900E.

Comment: I saw there are videos where people are just unchecking the "Show compatible hardware" and selecting the 9008 driver from the list. But is that safe?

Comment: disconnect battery and usb, short-circuit [test points](https://c.mi.com/us/thread-2355395-1-0.html) and connect usb to enter 9008 edl mode https://i.stack.imgur.com/780Kr.jpg

Comment: @alecxs Hi, I managed to flash an os successfully but there seem to be another problem. I can't get it to boot up. On connecting to pc it shows Diagnostic 900E. I tried pressing vol up + power for 20 sec. It disconnected from the PC an then again refreshed and showed Diagnostic 900E. Does this mean I'm stuck in EDL mode?

Comment: I flashed it multiple time and different versions of stock rom but nothing. I am still stuck in the EDL mode and the phone doesn't have any effect on pressing power button for howsoever long.

Comment: I have similar problem with poco M3 sometimes. this trick work for me. https://forum.xda-developers.com/posts/88260165

Comment: @alecxs This seems to work perfectly! The only problem is that I'm getting `Library.sahara - bytearray index out of range` error while executing any EDL command. Will see how to fix this. Thanks!